# Pull data from xively

Tags: java, android, json

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView thevalue;
    Button getJson;

    private static String url = "https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1465271593";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getJson = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata); //**(R.id.getdata is red)**
        getJson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            thevalue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.value); **//(R.id.value is red)**
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            getJson theParser = new getJson();  //**(It is in red lines)**

            JSONObject json = theParser.doIt(url);  //**(doIt is red)**
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            try {

                user = json.getJSONArray("datastreams");
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                String curval = c.getString("current_value");
                Log.i("JSONARR", user.toString());
                thevalue.setText(curval);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for the retrieving of data, but the words annotated above are either red or with red lines. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is code compilable?

Comment: There are errors so it is not compilable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.